# Tkinter Matplotlib and Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, tkinter

In the main loop, a 2 x 2 tkinter grid is cretaed with
one label in each cell of the first line.
In the second line, two Matplotlib figures are crated with a subplot
Two functions are in charge to dynamicly refresh the grid.
They are running each one in a thread.
The first line (two labels) is well refresh by the two functions. 
But, in the second line nothing ... no plot !

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib import style

def read_api1():
    n = 0
    while 1:
        n = n + 1
        texte1.config(text="fig1 " + str(n))
        ax1.plot([1,2], [12,14])
        time.sleep(2)
        ax1.cla()

def read_api2():
    m = 0
    while 1:
        m = m + 1
        texte2.config(text="fig2 " + str(m))
        ax2.plot([.1,.2,.3], [2,4,3])
        time.sleep(1)

main = Tk()
style.use("ggplot")

texte1 = Label(main, text="fig1")
texte1.grid(row=0,column=0)
fig1 = Figure(figsize=(2, 2), dpi=112)
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot()
fig1.set_tight_layout(True)
graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=main)
canvas = graph.get_tk_widget()
canvas.grid(row=1, column=0)

texte2 = Label(main, text="fig2")
texte2.grid(row=0,column=1)
fig2 = Figure(figsize=(2, 2), dpi=112)
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot()
fig2.set_tight_layout(True)
graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, master=main)
canvas = graph.get_tk_widget()
canvas.grid(row=1, column=1)

t = threading.Thread(target=read_api1)
t.start()
t = threading.Thread(target=read_api2)
t.start()

main.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

---

**EDIT:**

Some more details @furas:

- `read_api`2 is supposed to get data from a `WEB API` at specific time. So what you recommend (`after` method) should work.
- `read_api1` is supposed to acquire data from a serial port (`GPIO UART`). So the thread will be waiting for data beeing available for reading.

In that case, I don't see how to use the after method

In other words, the question is : how to refresh a matplotlib plot in a tkinter environnement based on asynchronous input ? The asynchronous serial data read cannot be in the mainloop, so I put it in the thread but even with `graph.draw()`, it does not work. Any suggestion ?

Comment: usually GUIs don't like to work in threads and only main thread may update widgets.

Comment: I added your new information in your question.

Comment: If you have new information then add to question, not to answers.  And at start you should write that you will read data from GPIO - it changes everything. Or now you would have to create new question on new page because it is new problem.

Comment: Now yo have to run `GPIO` in thread and use Queue to send data to main thread and main thread has to use `after()` to check `Queue` periodically and if there are new data then it should display new plot. I think I made something like this long time ago on Stackoverflow and maybe I have it in [examples on GitHub](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter)

Comment: as for `WEB API` - you can count `(specific_time - current_time)` an convert it to milliseconds and use result in `after(millisecond, ...)` to run function at secific time.

Comment: I added example which runs two threads which generate data in different speed and  send data to main thread using two `queues`. And main thread uses two `after()` to check two `queues` and update two plots.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. it needs `graph.draw()` to update/redraw plot
2. usually GUIs don't like to run in thread and it seems `graph.draw()` doesn't work in thread (at least on my Linux).

You may have to use `main.after(1000, main_api1)` to run the same function after `1000ms` (`1s`) without using `thread` and without blocking `mainloop()`

---

```
import tkinter as tk # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib import style
import random

# --- functions ---

def read_api1():
    global n

    n = n + 1
    texte1.config(text="fig1 " + str(n))

    ax1.cla()
    ax1.plot([1,2], [random.randint(0,10),random.randint(0,10)])
    graph1.draw()

    main.after(1000, read_api1)

def read_api2():
    global m

    m = m + 1
    texte2.config(text="fig2 " + str(m))

    ax2.cla()
    ax2.plot([.1,.2,.3], [random.randint(0,10),random.randint(0,10),random.randint(0,10)])
    graph2.draw()

    main.after(1000, read_api2)

# --- main ---

m = 0
n = 0

main = tk.Tk()
style.use("ggplot")

texte1 = tk.Label(main, text="fig1")
texte1.grid(row=0, column=0)

fig1 = Figure(figsize=(2, 2), dpi=112)
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot()
fig1.set_tight_layout(True)
graph1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=main)
canvas1 = graph1.get_tk_widget()
canvas1.grid(row=1, column=0)
#graph1.draw()

texte2 = tk.Label(main, text="fig2")
texte2.grid(row=0,column=1)
fig2 = Figure(figsize=(2, 2), dpi=112)
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot()
fig2.set_tight_layout(True)
graph2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, master=main)
canvas2 = graph2.get_tk_widget()
canvas2.grid(row=1, column=1)
#graph2.draw()

read_api1()
read_api2()

main.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** Example which runs two threads. Every threads generate data in different speed and use two `queue`s to send data to main thread. And main thread use two `after()` to check two queues and update two plots.

```
import tkinter as tk # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib import style
import random

import threading
import queue
import time

# --- functions ---

def WEB_API(queue):
    # it will run in thread

    print('WEB_API: start')

    while web_api_running:
        value = random.randint(1, 3)
        time.sleep(.1)
        print('WEB_API:', value)
        queue.put(value)


def GPIO_API(queue):
    # it will run in thread

    print('GPIO_API: start')

    while gpio_api_running:
        value = random.randint(1, 3)
        time.sleep(value)
        print('GPIO_API:', value)
        queue.put(value)


def read_api1():
    global n
    global data1

    if not queue1.empty():
        value = queue1.get()

        # remove first item and add new item at the the end
        data1 = data1[1:] + [value]

        n += 1
        texte1.config(text="fig1 " + str(n))

        ax1.cla()
        ax1.plot(range(10), data1)
        graph1.draw()

    main.after(100, read_api1)

def read_api2():
    global m
    global data2

    if not queue2.empty():
        value = queue2.get()

        # remove first item and add new item at the the end
        data2 = data2[1:] + [value]

        m = m + 1
        texte2.config(text="fig2 " + str(m))

        ax2.cla()
        ax2.plot([.1,.2,.3], data2)
        graph2.draw()

    main.after(100, read_api2)

# --- before GUI ---

# default data at start (to add new value at the end and remove first value)
data1 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
data2 = [0,0,0]

m = 0
n = 0

# queues to communicate with threads
queue1 = queue.Queue()
queue2 = queue.Queue()

# global variables to control loops in thread    
web_api_running = True 
gpio_api_running = True

# start threads and send queues as arguments
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=WEB_API,  args=(queue1,))
thread1.start()

thread2 = threading.Thread(target=GPIO_API, args=(queue2,))
thread2.start()

# --- GUI ---

main = tk.Tk()
style.use("ggplot")

texte1 = tk.Label(main, text="fig1")
texte1.grid(row=0, column=0)

fig1 = Figure(figsize=(2, 2), dpi=112)
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot()
fig1.set_tight_layout(True)
graph1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=main)
canvas1 = graph1.get_tk_widget()
canvas1.grid(row=1, column=0)

texte2 = tk.Label(main, text="fig2")
texte2.grid(row=0,column=1)
fig2 = Figure(figsize=(2, 2), dpi=112)
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot()
fig2.set_tight_layout(True)
graph2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, master=main)
canvas2 = graph2.get_tk_widget()
canvas2.grid(row=1, column=1)

# draw plots first time
ax1.plot(range(10),  data1)
ax2.plot([.1,.2,.3], data2)

# run after which will update data and redraw plots
read_api1()
read_api2()

main.mainloop()

# --- after GUI ---

# stop loops in threads
web_api_running = False
gpio_api_running = False

# wait for end of theads
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```